# ESX 4.1 installation

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-esxi

Can i install ESX 4.1 on my Pc with 2 GB of RAM but my VGA take min 128 shared from the memory so can i install ESX 4.1 without giving me the error of 1.8 GB is less than 2 GB?

how can i install ESX?

Comment: Install more RAM.

Comment: ok i upgrade now the RAM to 4 GB of RAM but now i have problem with the NIC card ,so what NIC card to buy to Esx 4.1 and cheap one

Comment: Check out http://www.vm-help.com//esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php to see which NIC cards will work.  This website usually has more hardware than vmware compatibilty site.

Answer (score 8):

Get more RAM. There isn't really any point for installing ESX on a machine with 2 Gigs of RAM.  You'll only be able to run one VM at a time which sort of defeats the point of ESX.

Comment: ok i upgrade now the RAM to 4 GB of RAM but now i have problem with the NIC card ,so what NIC card to buy to Esx 4.1 and cheap one

Comment: You can try VMware's compatibility tool at http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php